# Accessing a file on AWS S3 with spark via REST API

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to run a python file that is stored in AWS S3. I am using the following REST call:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:6066/v1/submissions/create --header "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data '{
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "s3n://<bucket-Name>/pi.py" ],
"appResource" : "s3n://<bucket-Name>/pi.py",
"clientSparkVersion" : "1.6.1",
"environmentVariables" : {
    "SPARK_ENV_LOADED" : "1"
},
"mainClass" : "org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit",
"sparkProperties" : {
"spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
"spark.app.name" : "Simple App",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "true",
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
"spark.master" : "spark://localhost:6066"
}
}'
```

But I am getting error:

```
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n
```

I have tried same call except the file was on my local machine and it worked. How can I set fs.s3n.impl, fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId and fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey values in REST call?

Please help.

Comment: Did you add the amazon-sdk to the master and worker classpaths? Or are they stored inside your uber jar?

Comment: How do i do that...

Answer (score 0):

you are going to need the hadoop-aws JAR on your CP, as well as jets3t 0.90 JAR ; the latter should be included by default (hadoop moved all aws stuff into a JAR which isn't currently included in Spark, see).

If you are using Hadoop 2.7+, I'd recommend you upgrade to using s3a URLs, which is the newer client; it needs the same JAR plus the AWS SDK which Yuval mentioned.

See: http://www.slideshare.net/steve_l/hadoop-hive-spark-and-object-stores